# Looking up values within a range of cells

Tags: arrays, excel, search, excel-formula, lookup

Suppose I have the following data table in Excel

```
Company Amount  Text
Oracle  $3,400  330 Richard ERP
Walmart $750    348 Mary ERP
Amazon  $6,880  xxxx Loretta ERP
Rexel   $865    0000 Mike ERP
Toyota  $11,048 330 Richard ERP
```

I want to go through each item in the "Text" column, search the item against the following range of names:

```
Mary 
Mike 
Janine 
Susan 
Richard 
Jerry 
Loretta
```

and return the name in the "Person" column, if found. For example:

```
Company Amount  Text    Person
Oracle  $3,400  330 Richard ERP Richard
Walmart $750    348 Mary ERP    Mary
Amazon  $6,880  xxxx Loretta ERP    Loretta
Rexel   $865    0000 Mike ERP   Mike
Toyota  $11,048 330 Richard ERP Richard
```

I've tried the following in Excel which works:

```
=IF(N2="","",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1,N2)),Sheet2!$A$1,
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$2,N2)),Sheet2!$A$2,
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$3,N2)),Sheet2!$A$3,
....
```

Where $A$1:$A$133 is my range and N2 is the "Text" column values; however, that is a lot of nested code and apparently Excel has a limit on the number of nested IF statements you can have.

Is there a simpler solution (arrays? VBA?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A)),N2))),1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: @Scott Looks great, but I've got no idea how it works. That means that I cannot use it myself in other situations ... Care to add some explanation? Or would you rather keep it as some secret magic formula? (Please keep in mind that you already refered to this solution in another question ...)

Comment: @PeterPesch the `INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A))` finds the last cell in the column that has text in it.  It is a method used to limit the number of iterations.  The `/` in the aggregate with a Boolean following forces either 0/1 depending on if it is False/True.  The `0` return errors that the `6` in the aggregate forces the formula to ignore, thus only returning the row numbers where the Boolean is true.  The Aggregate then looks at the remaining number and returns the lowest to the INDEX, but doing a simple evaluate on the formula would have given you that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to have a look at it later today. Currently on a computer with duch version of excel, so the formulas aren't easily recognisable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this computer runs Excel 2007 (which doesn't have the `AGGREGATE` function), so your formula returns an empty string now (beause it catches the error).

Comment: However, this system is good enough to analyse the rest of your formula. The `MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A)` is a nice trick; however, I would probably use a name for `=Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A))` as I would certainly be referring to that lookup table many times in my excel document.

Comment: That would reduce your formula to something like `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(my_lkp_table)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(my_lkp_table,N2))),1)),"")` or `=IFERROR(INDEX(my_lkp_table,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(my_lkp_table)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(my_lkp_table,N2))),1)),"")` (which I sadly cannot test on a machine with Excel 2007).

Comment: @Scott And I see that your `Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A))` is very robust. Much better than `OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1)` (which fails as soon as the list contains an empty cell).

Comment: @PeterPesch yes in the real world I would create a named range and use that, but that would be another instruction to some one who may not know anything about the kind of thing here.